# Dynamically allocate an object, will the members that aren't ptrs (not dynamically allocated) in the struct be in the stack instead of the heap?

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory

Say I have this struct:

```
typedef struct List_object list;
struct List_object {
    char* name;
    struct stat stats;
};
```

In main:

```
list** listObjects = malloc(sizeof(list*) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        listObjects[i] = malloc(sizeof(list));
        listObjects[i]->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 124);
    }
```

then I have a function that sets them:

```
void setListObjects(char* name, struct stat stats);
```

I was wondering if the data member **struct stat stats** in each object of the array **listObjects** will be in the heap as well?

Or will it only be **listObjects** and its data member **name** since both were allocated with **malloc**, and not **stats**?

Comment: All the dynamically allocated memory will be in the heap.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Since I didn't dynamically allocate the "struct stat stats" and set one of the " listObjects" elements to be tha, listObjects[i]->stats = stats inside the function: setListObjects(char* name, struct stat stats), would listObjects[i]->stats be in the stack only?

Comment: With `list** listObjects = malloc(sizeof(list) * n);` you create something of  a pointer to `list` and assign it to a pointer to pointer to `list`. The sizes do not match. Did you mean `list** listObjects = malloc(sizeof(list*) * n);`?

Comment: There are no such things as "stack" and "heap" in the C language. These words do not occur in the text of the standard. Your implementation may use stack and/or heap in order to implement the language, but these things are implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if the data member struct stat stats in each object of the array listObjects will be in the heap as well?

Yes. Every struct member will be allocated on the heap. Though note that while the pointer `name` itself in your example will be allocated together with the struct on the heap, what it points at could be anything.